# Mono.Security.Cryptography RijndaelManaged class issue using CFB-8 mode

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I'm writing to report about cryptography issue. The problem happens using `RijndaelManaged` class from the `System.Security.Cryptography`. It is important for me to use `RijndaelManaged` with `CFB-8` (FeedbackSize = 8) mode without padding (`PaddingMode.None`). Such settings configuration makes encrypted data size equal to the decrypted data size.

Unfortunately Mono (Mono Compiler for MVS2010 IDE v2.0.8152) compiled code throws exception on data encryption with message:

```
[Unhandled Exception: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: invalid block length at Mono.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricTransform.FinalEncrypt].
```

I made tests with the .NET framework 4.0 under Windows XP and Windows 7, using the native Visual Studio 2010 compiler. I found that the **native Microsoft .NET compiler does not throw any exceptions**, and the code example works well.

Below I have pasted two examples (Repro code), one for Mono which throws an exception and one for native C# compiler in this case there are no exceptions. Also I have also pasted links to online compilers to test the code.

**Why is the Mono Compiler throwing this exception?**

---

Mono code Sample (Online compiler for testing, [Compile Online](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php))

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Dela.Mono.Examples
{
   public class HelloWorld
   {
      public static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         string plainText = "This will be encrypted.";
            string plainText2 = "";

            RijndaelManaged aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();

            aesAlg.BlockSize = 128;
            aesAlg.KeySize = 256;
            aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
            aesAlg.FeedbackSize = 8;
            aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

            aesAlg.GenerateKey();
            aesAlg.GenerateIV();

            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor();

            MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
                using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt)) {
                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(msEncrypt.ToArray().Length); 
            Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msEncrypt.ToArray()));

            byte[] customArray = msEncrypt.ToArray();

            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor();

            MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(customArray);
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)) {
                using (StreamReader swDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt)) {
                    plainText2 = swDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(plainText2.Length); 
            Console.WriteLine(plainText2);


      }
   } 
}
```

---

Native C# Code Sample (Online compiler for testing, [Compile Online](http://rextester.com/runcode))

```
// Rextester.Program.Main is the entry point for your code. Don't change it.

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string plainText = "This will be encrypted.";
            string plainText2 = "";

            RijndaelManaged aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();

            aesAlg.BlockSize = 128;
            aesAlg.KeySize = 256;
            aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
            aesAlg.FeedbackSize = 8;
            aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

            aesAlg.GenerateKey();
            aesAlg.GenerateIV();

            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor();

            MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
                using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt)) {
                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(msEncrypt.ToArray().Length); 
            Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msEncrypt.ToArray()));

            byte[] customArray = msEncrypt.ToArray();

            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor();

            MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(customArray);
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)) {
                using (StreamReader swDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt)) {
                    plainText2 = swDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(plainText2.Length); 
            Console.WriteLine(plainText2);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug was fixed. The sources can be taken from the mono GIT repository.

master: e094d3dc0cf186f1de32d5340d847dc18aeca0e2

mono-2-10: 98e4842eb19dfd60000ada19e9bfb265fad7c84b

Comment: Do you know what the bug ID that was fixed?